# Find out if app was launched before

Tags: android

I got the following problem:
An app needs to know if another installed app was launched at least one time before.
I thought of creating a file on sd with the first app. And the second app knows that the first one was started at least one times before.
Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sharedpreferences:

on the first app that need to be launched at least one time: (On create method)

```
//This will store a string with a value "yessir" when the app is launched. You can tweak it a bit by adding something like if !launched string exist skip the creation to avoid creating the string at every launch.

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("launched", "yessir");
editor.commit();
```

On the second app:

```
        try {
            Context myContext = createPackageContext("package_name_of_the_first_app", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
            SharedPreferences pref = myContext.getSharedPreferences(
                    "my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String isItLaunched = pref.getString("launched", "");
            if (isItLaunched.equals("yessir") {
                // The first app got launched so do something
            } else {
                // the first app was not launched so do something else 
            }          
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
```